# how to compare two field with same value with different effect in one table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, case

i need to compare the value of two fields with the value of a textbox.

i have one table called `CITY`.

`name` and `zip` are the other two fields that are from this table.
Now my problem is that i want to compare the textbox with **zip** as well as **city** name
but its comparing only with city name.

[image: zip image]
[image: city image]

**My query is:**

```
SELECT id,CONCAT(name, ' - ', zipcode) as City FROM `ka13_city` WHERE `name` LIKE '%su%' or `zipcode` LIKE '%39%' order by name asc
```

Can you please give me some suggestions.

and one of my friends is telling me to use **CASE**.
so please share knowledge about how to use **CASE**

Comment: what is field type of `zipcode`?

Comment: do you want to only search rows having name like 'su' as well as zip like '39' ? or both cases ?

Comment: @Orifjon its simple string but in this '56XXXX' like this

Comment: @SKV anything of this either enter 'su' or 39 it should display respective result...

Comment: you mean select rows having su in name and zip + 39 in name and zip both condition should be fullfilled ?

Comment: i have only one textbox. user can enter name or they can enter zipcode, but my query can satisfy with both condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$city` is a variable to store user input for text city, maybe this is what you looking for :

```
$city = "surat";

$qry = "SELECT id,CONCAT(NAME, ' - ', zipcode) AS City 
    FROM `ka13_city` 
    WHERE CONCAT(UCASE(`name`), ' - ', UCASE(zipcode)) LIKE '%{$city}%' 
    ORDER BY NAME ASC";
```

Follow [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ucase) for more information about UCASE.

Comment: I have tried what you have posted here but **CONCAT** is not working fine in where condition can we try for another way.

Comment: thanks its working fine but some changes is there is here below

SELECT id,CONCAT(name, ' - ', zipcode) AS City_ZIP FROM `ka13_city` WHERE CONCAT(name,'-',zipcode) LIKE '%4700%'

or 

SELECT id,CONCAT(name, ' - ', zipcode) AS City_ZIP FROM `ka13_city` WHERE CONCAT(name,'-',zipcode) LIKE '%rai%'

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`SELECT id, CONCAT(name, ' - ', zipcode) as City FROM 'ka13_city' WHERE 'name' LIKE '%su%' and 'zipcode' LIKE '%39%' order by name asc`

Comment: Please tell the difference ?

Comment: The DIFFEREN6CE is IN the USE of `and` INSTEAD of `OR`.

Comment: `AND` is the difference. For exact match.